# jQuery hover 2 элемента

Tags: jquery

Помогите реализовать такое.
Есть 2 динамических блока добавленных на страницу через `$().html()`

Пускай это будут  `div_1` и `div_2`.

- `div_1` - по умолчанию виден.
- `div_2` - по умолчанию скрыт.

При ховере на `div_1` показывается `div_2` (он находится вплотную к `div_1`)

При переходе ховера с `div_1` на `div_2` - оба элемента видны.

При переходе ховера снова на `div_1` - `div_2` прячется, `div_1` - виден.

Если ховер **НЕ** находится на каком либо из этих элементов, все дивы скрываются. Сначала скрывается `div_2`, а через 2 секунды прячется `div_1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример реализации вашего вопроса:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').append('<div class="div_1"></div><div class="div_2"></div>');
  var first_hover = true;
  $(document).on('mouseover', '.div_1', function(){
    if(first_hover){
      $('.div_2').show();
      first_hover = false;
    }
  });
  $(document).on('mouseover', '.div_2', function(){
    $('.div_2').show();
  });
  $(document).on('mouseleave', '.div_1', function(){
    if(!$('.div_2').is(":hover")){
      $('.div_2').hide();
      setTimeout(function(){$('.div_1').hide();}, 1000);
    }    
  });
  
  $(document).on('mouseleave', '.div_2', function(){
    if(!$('.div_1').is(":hover")){
      $('.div_2').hide();
      setTimeout(function(){$('.div_1').hide();}, 1000);
    }
    else{
      $('.div_2').hide();
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
body{
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.div_1{
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
.div_2{
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```